# Returning custom HttpServletResponse from Spring AOP aspect does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I'm trying to implement a simple annotation `@RequiresLogin`.

```
package com.nonce.annotation;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RequiresLogin { }
```

Here's the `Aspect`

```
package com.nonce.aspect;

import com.nonce.annotation.RequiresLogin;
import com.nonce.security.SecurityUtils;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Component
@Aspect
public class SecurityManager {

    @Around("@annotation(com.nonce.annotation.RequiresLogin) && args(request,..)")
    public Object authenticate(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, HttpServletRequest request) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());
        HttpServletResponse response = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getResponse();
        if(!SecurityUtils.isLoggedIn(request)) {
            response.sendRedirect("/");
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

And then, I'm trying to use the annotation in one of my controllers.

```
package com.nonce.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.nonce.timeplex.annotation.RequiresLogin;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import com.nonce.security.SecurityUtils;
import com.nonce.utils.Constants;
import com.nonce.utils.URLStore;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(URLStore.INDEX)
public class ProfileController {

    @Autowired
    HttpSession session;

    @RequiresLogin
    @RequestMapping(value = URLStore.PROFILE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showProfile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap modelMap) {
        SecurityUtils.injectCSRFToken(session);
        return Constants.PROFILE;
    }
}
```

In the method `showProfile()`, when I remove the parameter `HttpServletResponse response`, the annotation does not work as in although the method call is intercepted, the redirect does not take place.

I'm trying to understand why does that happen? Any leads?

Comment: I cannot answer the actual question. I am an AOP expert, not a Spring user, and your question is not really related to Spring AOP. But I want to suggest better wording if I may. You wrote: _"trying to implement a simple annotation"_ No, you are trying to implement an **aspect** which should fire if it detects a certain annotation. You also wrote: _"when I remove the parameter (...), the annotation does not work"_ The annotation itself does not do anything, it just sits there. Again, the **aspect** is supposed to fire and execute the corresponding advice when it matches your joinpoint.

Comment: You might be reinventing the wheel here. Spring Security already has the ability to guard certain endpoints. Maybe you should look into that rather than trying to implement it yourself.